Error Message SINUMERIK - MBDDE application
Turning machine with Sinumerik system still reports:
WARNING: Application ´mbdde´ didn ´t  post InitComplete! Press ´énter´ and continue...
Can someone help us how we have to solve this problem?
Battery was change, we tried reset and no change .

Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask such questions.  Please post here: https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/us/en/threads/155/?page=0&pageSize=10.  Make sure to follow the guidelines here: https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/us/en/posts/tip-for-creating-a-new-thread/87964/?page=0&pageSize=10
